# Commn lisp コマンドライン引数の処理について

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

sbclで、以前作ったbmi計算機をコマンドライン引数からインスタンスを作成し、オブジェクトを作る様に改造しようとしています。

引数が2個の場合、`make-instance`で引数から、`person`インスタンスを作成し、とりあえず`person`の内容を表示しようとしていますが、コンパイルすると変数`person`が無いと怒られているようです。

以下がソースになりますが、どの様に修正したら良いでしょうか？

```lisp
;;;
;;; bmi.lisp
;;;
;;;

;;; クラス定義
(defclass bmi ()
  ((height :accessor bmi-height :initform 0 :initarg :height)
   (weight :accessor bmi-weight :initform 0 :initarg :weight)
   (bmi :accessor bmi-bmi :initform 0)))

;;; 初期化
(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((x bmi) &rest _)
  (let*  ((meter-height (/ (bmi-height x) 100))
          (tmp-value (/ (bmi-weight x) (* meter-height meter-height))))
   (setf (bmi-bmi x) (float (/ (floor (* tmp-value 10)) 10)))))

;; 肥満度
(defmethod fatness ((x bmi))
  (cond
    ((< (bmi-bmi x) 18.5) (format t "低体重"))
    ((< (bmi-bmi x) 25) (format t "標準体重"))
    ((< (bmi-bmi x) 30) (format t "肥満(1度)"))
    ((< (bmi-bmi x) 35) (format t "肥満(2度)"))
    ((< (bmi-bmi x) 40) (format t "肥満(3度)"))
    (t (format t "肥満(4度)"))))

(if (= (length *posix-argv*) 3)
    (let* ((tall-and-weight (cdr *posix-argv*))
       (tall (read-from-string (car tall-and-weight)))
       (weight (read-from-string (second tall-and-weight))))
      (defparameter person (make-instance 'bmi :height tall :weight weight))
      (describe person)) ;; personが無いと怒られる
    ())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

表示されるメッセージは以下の通りで、コンパイル時のワーニングです。(実行時には `person` の内容が表示されます)

```lisp
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     PERSON
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
```

CLHS に以下の説明があります。

[CLHS: Macro DEFPARAMETER, DEFVAR](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm)

> `defparameter` and `defvar` normally appear as a top level form, but it is meaningful for them to appear as non-top-level forms. However, the compile-time side effects described below only take place when they appear as top level forms.
> 　　　　　　:
>
> **Side Effects**:
>
> **If a `defvar` or `defparameter` form appears as a top level form, the compiler must recognize that the name has been proclaimed special**. However, it must neither evaluate the initial-value form nor assign the dynamic variable named name at compile time.

なので、**コンパイル時には** `let*` 内で `defparameter` で定義されている `person` は special 変数(global scope)ではなく local 変数として扱われることになります。
対応策としては、top-level で `person` を定義するか(special 変数なので慣例的に `*person*` としています)、

```lisp
(defparameter *person* nil)
(if (= (length *posix-argv*) 3)
    (let* ((tall-and-weight (cdr *posix-argv*))
           (tall (read-from-string (car tall-and-weight)))
           (weight (read-from-string (second tall-and-weight))))
      (defparameter *person* (make-instance 'bmi :height tall :weight weight))
      (describe *person*))
    ())
```

`person` を local 変数として定義することが考えられます。

```lisp
(if (= (length *posix-argv*) 3)
    (let* ((tall-and-weight (cdr *posix-argv*))
           (tall (read-from-string (car tall-and-weight)))
           (weight (read-from-string (second tall-and-weight)))
           (person (make-instance 'bmi :height tall :weight weight)))
      (describe person))
    ())
```

Comment: 詳しい説明までありがとうございます。ちょうど後者で解決したところでした。