# listからcdrして得たstringをread-from-stringすると文字列ではないとエラーが出る

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

[先の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/98589)で引数`*posix-argv*`を処理しているときに、引数は3つだから最後の要素は

```shell
sbcl 170 70
```

として`sbcl`を起動してみて、

```lisp
(cdr (cdr *posix-argv*))
```

で取れると最初は思いました。

しかし、`read-from-string`で、上の値を処理すると、文字列ではないと怒られました。

試しに`type-of`で、型を確認すると

```lisp
(type-of (cdr (cdr *posix-argv*)))
```

の結果は`cons`でした。

これは、上の結果が、"70"が取得されているように見えて
実際は`("70" . nil)`が取得されているため、`"70"`を取得するにはもう一度`car`しないとダメだからという理解で合っているでしょうか？
`nth`で引数を取得すると`read-from-string`が成功して、`(cdr (cdr *posix-argv*)`が失敗するのがモヤッとするので質問させてください。

Comment: 過去の質問も含めて、タイトルは「〇〇について」と曖昧な表現で切らず、内容が伝わるものを心掛けてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 実際は `("70" . nil)` が取得されているため、`"70"` を取得するにはもう一度carしないとダメだからという理解で合っているでしょうか？

はい。

[CLHS: Accessor CAR, CDR, CAAR, CADR, CDAR...](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_car_c.htm)

> **Syntax**:
>
> cdr x => object
>
> **Description**:
>
> If x is a cons, cdr returns the cdr of that cons. If x is nil, cdr returns nil.

※ Lisp における `list` は cons cell でもあります。

```lisp
$ sbcl 170 70
This is SBCL 2.2.9.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

* *posix-argv*
("sbcl" "170" "70")

* (listp *posix-argv*)
T
* (consp *posix-argv*)
T

* '("sbcl" . ("170" . ("70" . nil)))
("sbcl" "170" "70")

* (equal *posix-argv* '("sbcl" . ("170" . ("70" . nil))))
T

* (cdr (cdr '("sbcl" . ("170" . ("70" . nil)))))
("70")
* (caddr '("sbcl" . ("170" . ("70" . nil))))
"70"
```